# merging files with same name in different subdirectories in R

Tags: r

Let's assume that we have the following directory organization:

```
~/data1/file1
~/data1/file2
~/data1/file3

~/data2/file1
~/data2/file2
~/data2/file3

~/data3/file1
~/data3/file2
~/data3/file3
```

How can combine the columns in each of the files to something like this:

```
~/data/file1 (containing all columns from file1 in each of the subdirectories)
~/data/file2 (containing all columns from file2 in each of the subdirectories)
~/data/file3 (containing all columns from file3 in each of the subdirectories)
```

Comment: read in the files, then rbind the ones you want to combine

Comment: May be I was not clear. Each of the files contain only one column data and the final files should have three columns.The total number of individual files in each of the sub-directories is more than 10,000

Comment: @JohnMusau in that case use `cbind`

Comment: This question could be really interesting, and would probably attract some really good answers, if you showed what you've tried, and describe exactly what you're trying to do. People tend to not answer questions that don't show any effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that I understand it correctly, you can try:

Here, I created 9 `.txt` files in three directories `data1`, `data2`, and `data3`, which is just under my working directory `TestN` so as to emulate the situation.

```
 filelist <- list.files(recursive=TRUE)
 filelist #As you mentioned, each directory has `file1`, `file2`, `file3` with `.txt extension.
 #[1] "data1/file1.txt" "data1/file2.txt" "data1/file3.txt" "data2/file1.txt"
 #[5] "data2/file2.txt" "data2/file3.txt" "data3/file1.txt" "data3/file2.txt"
 #[9] "data3/file3.txt"
```

Then, I split the `filelist`, by their basenames, ie. `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` etc. and then read the individual files within the split folder by using another `lapply` and then `cbind` the single column files that belong to the same `basename`.

```
 lst1 <- lapply(split(filelist, basename(filelist)), function(x) do.call(cbind, lapply(x, 
function(y) read.table(y, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ""))))
```

Created another folder `data`

```
 dir.create("data")
 mainDir <- paste(getwd(), "data", sep="/")
 setwd(mainDir) #change the working directory to mainDir from the previous code
```

Now, I created some sub-folders within the mainDir

```
 subDir <- gsub("\\..*", "", unique(basename(filelist)))
 subDir
 #[1] "file1" "file2" "file3"

 lapply(subDir, dir.create)
```

Write the files to the concerned subfolders.

```
 lapply(seq_along(lst1), function(i) write.table(lst1[[i]], paste(getwd(), subDir[i], 
names(lst1)[i], sep = "/"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
read.table("file1/file1.txt", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
#  Col1 Col1 Col1
#1    7    7   17
#2    5    4   42
#3    3    5   53
#4    2    2    2


read.table("file2/file2.txt", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
#   Col1 Col1 Col1
# 1    3    3   32
# 2    8    9    9
# 3    9    9   92
# 4    5    5    5

 list.files(recursive=TRUE)
 # [1] "file1/file1.txt" "file2/file2.txt" "file3/file3.txt"
```